# MERGE vs DROP Table and Rebuild Indexes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, log-shipping

I have a "log shipped" copy of a database that lives at a third party.  Log shipping runs every 15 minutes at which time all connections to the database are dropped.  The database is used for reporting purposes.

I have decided to pull some of the data from the log shipped (read only) database into a new database refreshed nightly.  This will allow users to connect to the new database without risk of loosing connectivity due to log shipping. (It also allows more granular security permissions to be used, since the read-only copy can't be edited)

I can think of 2 patterns to accomplish this.

1. Drop Table, Create Table, Create Indexes
2. use the MERGE statement to insert/update/delete records

I have implemented the solution using method 1 above, and it works just fine.

It feels a bit heavy to me to drop all of the data every day.  Are there any side effects to method 1 above that should push me over to using method 2?

To provide a sense of scale, I am only syncing 3 tables,

```
Table 1 - 38 columns - 13,110 rows
Table 2 - 82 columns - 17,421 rows
Table 3 - 22 columns - 249 rows
```

The resulting database is ~1.3 GB.  (There are some other tables in there as well)

I would appreciate guidance on Method 1 vs 2, and whether there is another method that I am not thinking about.

Comment: Have you looked into transactional replication? I'm don't have enough know-how on it to actually help more but it might be an option worth looking at

Comment: I have not looked into that in the context of this question, because log shipping is the method that our vendor supports for getting us a copy of the data.  I assume that since the log-shipped copy is read-only, I could not use it for transactional replication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` and `INSERT` would be more efficient than either dropping or merging.

Comment: I like that.  I will give that a go, and compare it to my drop/create.  Thanks!   (I will re-visit this question later today once I kick the tires on that).

Comment: Thanks for this.  From a clock perspective, both methods complete in ~12 seconds.  I like how clean `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT INTO` are compared to rebuilding all of the indexes.  I had to make a slight modification to my stored procedures to use CTE's rather than #Temp tables to get the 'INSERT INTO' to work but with that hurdle cleared I now have cleaner code.  Thanks.